# Visual Studio 2022 - Hot Reload Disabled

Tags: c#, hot-reload, visual-studio-2022

Trying to use the new "hot reload" feature in VS 2022.  I have 4 .NET 5 projects (Blazor, API, Tests and Class Library).   2 of them are set to start on debug (Blazor and API).

The hot reload button is disabled.  I cannot seem to figure out why.

Is there a list of "limitations" outlined on Hot Reload?  I have not been able to find documentation on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET hot reload is part of .NET 6. You'll have to upgrade your projects.

Comment: do you have a reference to the list of limitations?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-hot-reload/

Comment: ill try to upgrade and see if it works